# Set state on variable declared jsx

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've been making a sidebar in React, of which i want to be able to switch out the content.

If I select an item from the screen I want the sidebar to update with its info, and I've done this by making a callback setting the item in a sidebar.js class. After that I want to set the right content for the sidebar.

I solved this by making sidebar.js hold different contentstates in its state and updating an index, and also to set the item as a state.

My problem is I want to access the item in one of the content states, but it doesn't seem to be updating.

The problem I have is that even after a setState({activeItem:item}) the prop item in contentX is still null!

I've tried setting a callback on setState, first updating the item and then setting the content but to no avail.

Anyone have a clue?

```js
class Sidebar extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    var placeHolder = <b> placeholder </b>;
    this.state = {activeItem: "I want to update this", activeContent: [placeHolder], activeIndex: 0}
  
    var content1 = <Content1 item={this.state.activeItem}> </Content1>
    this.contentBox = [content1]
  }
  
  render(){
  const { activeIndex, activeContent } = this.state
    return(
      <div>
        {activeContent[activeIndex]}

        <button onClick={() => this.setState({
          activeContent: [this.contentBox],
          activeIndex: 0, 
          activeItem: "hello"})}> 
        </button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}


class Content1 extends React.Component{  
  render(){
    return(
       <b> {this.props.item} </b>
    )
  }
}


ReactDOM.render(
  <Sidebar />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="react"></div>
```

Comment: Try to always use `setters` and `getters` for `state`. You should add more code context so we can test the issue.

Comment: `item={this.state.activeItem}` doesn't in any way link `item` with the **property** `this.state.activeItem`; it reads the *value* of `this.state.activeItem` *as it is then* and sets that as the value of `item`. How to fix it depends a lot on how it's used. Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button) to make it **runnable**. Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/).

Comment: Updated with a code snippet!

Comment: To test if it works please change `this.contentBox` with `[<Content1 item={this.state.activeItem} />]`

Comment: This yields the same result

Answer (score 0):

State should be used only to store values that will be used with in the component. However, one should not generate the components and store them in state.

In the below code, the state `actievContent` is set with a component with old `item` value. Say your states `activeItem` was with value `hello1` and in the below code, your `Content` would be genreated with value `hello1` and get stored in `activeContent` rather than `hello` which you might expect. So your `Content1` won't get the new state value you are setting which is `hello` in this case.

```
<button onClick={() => this.setState({
  activeContent: [<Content1 item={this.state.activeItem} />],
  activeIndex: 0, 
  activeItem: "hello"})}> 
</button>
```

Instead you will have to do something like this.

```
<button onClick={() => this.setState({
  activeIndex: 0,
  activeItem: "hello"})}> 
</button>
```

Then in render method, you have to call the component with correct values. Instead of `activeContent`, place the component and pass the correct props to it.

```
render(){
 return(
  <div>
    <Content1 item={this.state.activeItem} />
    <button onClick={() => this.setState({
      activeIndex: 0, 
      activeItem: "hello"})}> 
    </button>
  </div>)
}
```